# android program for get all boundry position of bitmap

Tags: android, graphics, canvas

i am newer to android. i want to develop 2D game in android.

1) i want sample program or some idea for get boundry position of bitmap......

2)  i want to some link about game development in android for preparly.

3) Mostly i want to draw some thing by using canvas method. so try to provide some material related to canvas method in android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this brother

http://organicandroid.blogspot.com/2010/08/starting-to-play-with-graphics.html

Seriously this is one of best thing in this concern for sure. It like provided me with a framework to develop 2D games easily.

Comment: Thank u so much. now i make puzzile game. in my game i want to connect the same sprites via dot.  i want to draw line horizontally or vertically between dots rather then other areas. i nee dto get boundary position of each dots.. how to get this?

Comment: your welcome IRA. For developiong 2D gamnes . three things are important.first how you can move object. Second how you can detect touch events at all the points of screen. and how to detect collision between two object in the screen. i acquire this from this tutorial.